# Regex match multiple pattern

Tags: regex, perl

Below is my test string:

```
Object: TLE-234DSDSDS324-234SDF324ER
  Page location: SDEWRSD3242SD-234/324/234 (1)
    org-chart           Lorem ipsum dolor    consectetur adipiscing          # Colorado
    234DSDSDS324-32-4/2/7-page2 (2) loc log  Apr 18 21:42:49 2017           1
      Page information: 3.32.232.212.23, Error: fatal, Technique: color
        Comments: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      Validation status: Lorem ipsums dolors sits amets, consectetur adipiscing elit
       Positive control-export: Validated
  Page location: SDEWRSD3242SD-SDF/234/324 (5)
    org-chart           Lorem ipsum dolor    consectetur adipiscin          # Arizona
    234DSDSDS324-23-11/1/0-page1 (1) loc log Apr 18 21:42:49 2017           1
      Page information: 3.32.232.212.23, Error: log, Technique: color
        Comments: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Validation status: Lorem ipsums dolors sits amets, consectetur adipiscing elit
       Positive control-export: Validated
```

I need to capture strings after the "Page location: ",  "Object: " and "Comments: "

For example:

Object: **TLE-234DSDSDS324-234SDF324ER** - Group 1

Page location: **SDEWRSD3242SD-234/324/234 (1)** - Group 2

Page location: **SDEWRSD3242SD-SDF/234/324 (5)** - Group 3

Comments: **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.** - Group 4

Comments: **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.** - Group 5

Here is my [regex URL](https://regex101.com/r/t15dD8/7/).

I am able to capture the strings but the regex won't capture if any one of the string is repeated.

Comment: You're having problems if ie `Page location` occurs multiple times, is this right?

Comment: Yes. @Jan.. Page location and Comments

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/t15dD8/8 ?

Comment: Exactly, but it is not matching if i add one more Page location and Comments in the test string?

Comment: Is all this in one string (or is it in separate lines) -- or, how do you get this data into the program? Is "_Page location:_" unique, so that you always need what follows it? How far after "_Page location_" do you need to capture -- to the frst newline?  This is all shown "inside" of one "_Object_" -- are there multiple such sections in your string/file?

Comment: Thanks @zdim 1. Separated Lines 2. Yes "Page location" is unique. 3. how far? - until the end of line (highlighted in the question) 4. Yes, this all should show inside of one object.

Comment: OK, thanks.  How do those lines come -- while reading a file (orare they  in an array)? Are there multiple such "_Object_" things and do you have to distinguish to which "_Object_" which "_Page location_"s belong?

Comment: Also -- what do those _Group 1_ (etc) mean -- do you want that in output?  I've posted a basic take on this, let me know about the quesitons in the above two comments and I'll adjust the post if needed.

Comment: @zdim How do those lines come? - This test string is from a device (after executing a particular command). Are there multiple such "Object" things and do you have to distinguish to which "Object" which "Page location"s belong?  - Yes, you are right. :)  what do those Group 1,2... - It just captured string as in the regex101 tool. Thanks for your support.

Comment: At some point you gotta ask yourself whether writing a basic parser should be preferable to a complex regular expression.

Comment: @paddy Oh yeah, completely agree. I barely got to ask that (my hands went for the parser on their own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(See comments below the question for the problem description.)

The data is in a multi-line string, with multiple sections starting with `Object:`. Within each there are multiple lines starting with phrases `Page location:` and `Comments:`. The rest of the line for all these need be captured, and all organized by `Object`s.

Instead of attempting a tortured multi-line "single" regex, break the string into lines and process section by section.  This way the problem becomes a very simple one.

The results are stored in an array of hashrefs; each has for keys the shown phrases.  Since they can appear more than once per section their values are arrayrefs (with what follows them on the line).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $input_string = '...'; 
my @lines = split /\n/, $input_string;

my $patt = qr/Object|Page location|Comments/;

my @sections;
for (@lines) 
{
    next if not /^\s*($patt):\s*(.*)/;

    push @sections, {}  if $1 eq 'Object';

    push @{ $sections[-1]->{$1} }, $2;
}

foreach my $sec (@sections) {
    foreach my $key (sort keys %$sec) {
        say "$key:";
        say "\t$_" for @{$sec->{$key}};
    }   
}
```

With the input string copied (suppressed above for brevity), the output is

```
Comments:
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  [...] 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  [...]
Page location:
        SDEWRSD3242SD-234/324/234 (1)
        SDEWRSD3242SD-SDF/234/324 (5)
Object:
        TLE-234DSDSDS324-234SDF324ER
```

A few comments.

Once the `Object` line is found we add a new hashref to `@sections`.  Then the match for a pattern is set as a key and the rest of its line added to its arrayref value. This is done for the current (so last) element of `@sections`.

This adds an empty string if a pattern had nothing following. To disallow add `next if not $2;`

Note. An easy and common way to print complex data structures is via the core module [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html).  But also see [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm) for a much more compact printout.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but does OP need to restart his collection of data for each new object? In that case I'd use an array of hashes; start with an empty hash, capture into it until a new 'Object:' is seen, at which point a new empty anonymous hash is pushed onto the array and data is captured into that. Totally agree that a loop is a far better solution here than trying to compress the logic into a single regex!

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Yes, this needs to be adjusted if multiple `Object` sections exist and need be distinguished.  I asked a question, in comments and in the answer itself, and am waiting :).  The approach with one regex assumes that all data is available in a string, which isn't clear.  My question was answered that it's "_separate lines_" and then reading a file is common ... I am waiting on that clarification as well.